# Solving $n$ coupled equations numerically in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-equations

I would like to solve the following equations simultaneously and numerically for all $X, Y, Z, W$ where `i = 1:Nw, j = 1:Nl, k = 1:K`.

$W_\text{net1}$, $W_\text{net2}$, $m_\text{net1}$, and $m_\text{net2}$ are given.

How can I apply `solve()` or any other function to numerically find the values of $X, Y, Z, W$?

[image]

Here is the code for implementing the above equation in matlab.

```matlab
Nw = 2; Nl=3; K=2;
ivec = 1 : Nw;
jvec = 1 : Nl;
W_net1 = randi([-123, 123], Nw, K);
W_net2 = randi([-123, 123], Nl, K); 
m_net1 = randi([-123, 123], Nw, K); 
m_net2 = randi([-123, 123], Nl, K); 

for k = 1 : K
    for i = ivec
        X(i, k) = 2*(1 - 2*W(i,k))/((1 - 2*W(i,k))*(1 + W_net1(i,k)) + W(i,k)*W_net1(i,k)*(1 - (2*W(i,k))^m_net1(i,k)));
        ii = setdiff(ivec, i);
        tW1 = prod( 1 - X(ii, k) );
        tW2 = prod( 1 - Y(jvec, k) );
        W(i,k) = 1 - tW1 * tW2;
    end
    for j = jvec
        Y(j, k) = 2*(1 - 2*Z(j,k))/((1 - 2*Z(j,k))*(1 + W_net2(j,k)) + Z(j,k)*W_net2(j,k)*(1 - (2*Z(j,k))^m_net2(j,k)));
        i = ivec;
        tZ1 = prod(1 - X(i, k));
        jj = setdiff(jvec, j);
        tZ2 = prod(1 - Y(jj, k));
        tZ3 = tZ2 * tZ1;
        Z(j,k) = 1 - tZ3;
        S(j,k) = Y(j, k) * tZ3;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of approaching the problem you posted is to use [fsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html).

You can start by creating a file with a function that returns the difference $dX$, $dY$, $dW$ and $dZ$ between an estimate of $X$, $Y$, $W$ and $Z$ and the respective expressions for these variables, $f_X$, $f_Y$, $f_W$ and $f_Z$ that you presented in your post:
$$\begin{align}
dX(i,k) &= f_X(X,Y,W,Z) - X(i,k) \\
dY(j,k) &= f_Y(X,Y,W,Z) - Y(j,k) \\
dW(i,k) &= f_W(X,Y,W,Z) - W(i,k) \\
dZ(j,k) &= f_Z(X,Y,W,Z) - Z(j,k)
\end{align}$$

However, in order to call this function it's easier if you map the variables into a matrix $U$ of size $Nw + Nl + Nw + Nl$ by $K$. This way, you can use the matrix $U$ as the [function argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/matrix-arguments.html). The [parameters can be passed to the function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) by using function handles.

After creating the file with the function, your main program should define an initial guess (can it be all zeros, for instance?) and call [fsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html).

---

**Edit:**

In order to define the function, you'll need to create a file called `fun_dif.m` with the following content:

```
function dU = fun_dif(U, Nw, Nl, K, W_net1, W_net2, m_net1, m_net2)

ivec = 1 : Nw;
jvec = 1 : Nl;

X(ivec, 1:K) = U(ivec, 1:K);
Y(jvec, 1:K) = U(Nw + jvec, 1:K);
W(ivec, 1:K) = U(Nl + Nw + ivec, 1:K);
Z(jvec, 1:K) = U(Nw + Nl + Nw + jvec, 1:K);
dU = zeros(Nw + Nl + Nw + Nl, K); % initialize the difference vector

for k = 1 : K
    for i = ivec
        dU(i, k) = 2*(1 - 2*W(i,k))/((1 - 2*W(i,k))*(1 + W_net1(i,k)) + W(i,k)*W_net1(i,k)*(1 - (2*W(i,k))^m_net1(i,k))) - X(i, k);
        ii = setdiff(ivec, i);
        tW1 = prod( 1 - X(ii, k) );
        tW2 = prod( 1 - Y(jvec, k) );
        dU(Nl + Nw + i, k) = 1 - tW1 * tW2 - W(i,k);
    end
    for j = jvec
        dU(Nw + j, k) = 2*(1 - 2*Z(j,k))/((1 - 2*Z(j,k))*(1 + W_net2(j,k)) + Z(j,k)*W_net2(j,k)*(1 - (2*Z(j,k))^m_net2(j,k))) -  Y(j, k);
        i = ivec;
        tZ1 = prod(1 - X(i, k));
        jj = setdiff(jvec, j);
        tZ2 = prod(1 - Y(jj, k));
        tZ3 = tZ2 * tZ1;
        dU(Nw + Nl + Nw + j, k) = 1 - tZ3 -  Z(j,k);
        S(j,k) = Y(j, k) * tZ3;
    end
end
```

Note that it's mostly your code with the computation of the difference $dU$ between the estimate from the formulas and the current value $U$.

Then, in your main program you can have

```
Nw = 2;
Nl=3;
K=2;
W_net1 = randi([-123, 123], Nw, K);
W_net2 = randi([-123, 123], Nl, K); 
m_net1 = randi([-123, 123], Nw, K); 
m_net2 = randi([-123, 123], Nl, K); 

f = @(U)fun_dif(U, Nw, Nl, K, W_net1, W_net2, m_net1, m_net2); % create a function handle
U0 = 0.5 + zeros(Nw + Nl + Nw + Nl, K); % initial estimate is 0.5 for all matrices
UU = fsolve(f,U0); % UU will have the final solution
X(ivec, 1:K) = UU(ivec, 1:K);
Y(jvec, 1:K) = UU(Nw + jvec, 1:K);
W(ivec, 1:K) = UU(Nl + Nw + ivec, 1:K);
Z(jvec, 1:K) = UU(Nw + Nl + Nw + jvec, 1:K);
```

---

**Edit:**

It might be worthy to note that
$$ Z(j,k) = 1 - \frac{S(j,k)}{Y(j,k)}$$
and
$$ W(i,k) = 1 -\frac{S(j,k) (1 - Y(j,k))}{Y(j,k) (1 - X(i,k))} = 1 - \bigg(1 - Z(j,k) \bigg) \frac{1 - Y(j,k)}{1 - X(i,k)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, I am not sure if I got you quite well.  Could you please tell me how I can define f here? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Susan 
I haven't tested the code, so it might have bugs. Nevertheless, I tried to present the idea of the program. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The code works well and now I understand the approach you took to solve the problem. I DO appreciate your help .

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I would do a full numerical approach like the one I did above. Following your comment above, the 'W_net2`are the "variables", together with $X$, $W$, $Y$ and $Z$; and $S$ are treated as fixed parameters. I'm sure you can adapt my code to work like this.  Perhaps there is a simpler way to solve this if (some of) the equations above have analytical solutions, but I'm unable to see how to get them.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I think there is something in your answer that I didn't get that quite well. If S are treated as fixed parameters, why in the editing code above, you consider `S(jvec, 1:K) = U(Nw + Nl + Nw + Nl + jvec, 1:K);` Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As I said, I didn't get you quite well but from what I understood from your reply I give S as an input of `fun_dif` and calculate all 5 variables `W_net2`, `X`, `Y`, `W`, and `Z`. The problem that I am dealing with is by changing the S, the values of X and Y aren't changed! while they should be. I know I took your time a lot, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're right @Susan, the $S$ part was wrong and I rolled back to the previous version of my post.  Regarding the second question, note that, if I'm not mistaken:  $$ Z(j,k) = 1 - \frac{S(j,k)}{Y(j,k)}$$ and $$ W(i,k) = 1 - \frac{S(j,k) (1 - Y(j,k))}{(1 - X(i,k)) Y(j,k)} \ .$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It was very helpful. Now, with the modification you mentioned, Z and W change with S and so X and Y. I Do appreciate your help. Thanks again